# "Hex digits in character string" error when installing a package

Tags: r, escaping, install.packages

When  trying to install a package, I have been finding the "Hex digits in character string" error.  This has been robuts even to trying to change all destinations directories I am aware of (`\` for `\\` and `/`; working over the `.libPaths`).  I have also alternatively tried to download the packages manually to install them from source, but there is something behind I cannot access.

```
install.packages("AER",destdir = "C:/Users/catatau/Downloads", 
lib = "C:/Users/catatau/OneDrive/Documentos/R/win-library/3.6" )
```

And the output is:

```
    There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
    binary source needs_compilation
AER  1.2-9 1.2-10             FALSE

installing the source package ‘AER’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/AER_1.2-10.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2235716 bytes (2.1 MB)
downloaded 2.1 MB

R error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting "'C:\U"
Execution interrupted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘AER’ had non-zero exit status
```

I understand that the problem lies behind one of the misinterpretation of the paths to the decompression of the packages (and the fact that `\` is an escape), but I am puzzled about how to solve that within `install.packages` process.

Answer (score 0):

After removing the .Rprofile file and uninstalling VSCode things resumed to work.